# Resize Div Width with button click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an iFrame resize in width when I click a button. Ultimately, I will want to have various buttons for breakpoints, ie. 1024, 680, 480, 380 where the iFrame will resize to that size. 
I started here, but cannot get anything to work.

http://uswebpros.net/examples/mobile/test.php

Comment: check this....i think this is probabaly what u want.....
: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718090/2903316

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery..

```
   $('.button').on('click',function(e) {
       $('#yourdiv').css('width','yourwidth');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#slider").animate({
         width: '360px'
        }, 1000);
     });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25RSE/1/)

Comment: Works great in the fiddle, but I can't get it working in my server. http://uswebpros.net/examples/mobile/test.php